# Docker compose image container

Tags: docker

Como interligar 3 imagens no docker-compose ? 
eu gostaria que o elasticsearch, kibana e panthomJS fossem inseridos em apenas 1 container, porém só consegui o elasticsearch com o kibana.

Como posso fazer isso? Qualquer informação a respeito com qualquer versão eu posso me virar depois.

Answer (score 2):

Eu tenho um **docker-compose** com as configurações do **elastic** e do **kibana**, basta você inserir o outro serviço que você deseja, caso você copie esse código daqui cuidado com a identação.

Para subir os serviços basta `docker-compose up -d`

Perceba que deixei um `XXXX` adicione as configurações de usuario e senha que deseja. Lembrando que eles não vão executar no mesmo container, mas sim em uma rede de containers.

```
version: "2"
    services:
      elasticsearch:
        image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.1"
        container_name: elasticsearch
        environment:
            - "discovery.type=single-node"
            - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=XXXX
            - xpack.security.enabled=true
        volumes:
          - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        ports:
            - 9200:9200

      kibana:
          image: "docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.3.1"
          container_name: kibana
          environment:
            - ELASTICSEARCH_URL="elasticsearch:9200"
            - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=XXXX
            - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=XXXX
            - xpack.security.enabled=true
          links:
           - elasticsearch
          ports: 
            - 5601:5601
          depends_on: 
            - elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro passo no docker-compose é criar a rede, o segundo passo é em cada um dos containers descritos no compose, especificar o uso dessa rede. A partir desse ponto você pode referenciar cada serviço por seu nome.

Tenho um [exemplo de docker-compose com ElasticSearch, LogStash Kibana e RabbitMQ](https://github.com/docker-gallery/EnterpriseApplicationLog/)

Espero ajudar!

Comment: o link está quebrado, está dando 404

Comment: Resolvido @CaioAugustoPapai origado!

Comment: Uma resposta somente por link ficaria mais adequada como um comentário.